# WHERE clause on join adding 4 seconds to execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

```
SELECT journey.id
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN service ON journey.service = service.id
JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pl.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = "TMTL"
```

Above is an SQL query that takes on average 0.1 - 0.3 seconds to run.

For some reason, as soon as a I append `AND journey_day.day = 3` to the `WHERE` clause it adds an extra 4 seconds to the execution time. It is for this reason that I am posting this question.

Every column in the `journey_day` table has indexing of some sort.

```
id(INT 11) | journey(VARCHAR 128) | day(TINYINT 1)
```

The `id` is the primary key, the `journey` and `day` columns are both indexed. The table is joined with absolutely no problems, but as soon as the `WHERE` clause questions the table, execution time goes up by far too much for my liking.

The `journey_day` table is just there to determine which day the `journey` runs on. For example, if a journey runs on Wednesday and Thursdays, the journey would have its identifier in the journey column and then 3, same thing in another row but with 4.

Any ideas why this huge delay in execution time is happening?

**EDIT**

Result of an `EXPLAIN` prepended to the query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFXVo.png

Comment: prepend your query with `EXPLAIN`. Then you can use where MySQL use indexes and where not. This might help you improving your query and/or indexes.

Comment: @MrTux Sorry, forgot to mention I tried that. I'm not sure I totally understand what this tells me but here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/QrjZEHy.png

Comment: Is `id INT(11) | journey(VARCHAR 128) | day(TINYINT 1)` a multi column index? If yes, it might not be usable - it's only usable if you filter id, journay and day. - it won't help you if you just filter for `day`

Comment: @MrTux No, each key is unique to a single column

Comment: Did you try modifying the join condition to `JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id AND journey_day.day = 3`. That might help, because you'll filter during the JOIN itself and make the data set smaller.

Comment: @JosephB Yes, roughly the same execution time (3-4 secs)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that MySQL is choosing a different execution plan when you add that predicate.

You could compare the EXPLAIN output of the two queries, the one with the `journey_day.day=3` predicate and the one without.

I'd venture a guess that MySQL is choosing a different join order, and MySQL is opting to use an index that has `day` as a leading column when the predicate is included. And likely that's causing a lot more rows to be accessed and examined, or possibly MySQL is generating a large intermediate set before it filters out rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer spencer. I think you are along the right lines.  Something weird is going on. It's almost like MySQL is choosing to ignore the indexes. I'm not sure if I can derive anything from the `EXPLAIN`s myself, but I put them side by side and they are exactly the same. Does that tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using both the `journey_day.journey` and `journey_day.day` columns, a multi-column index would be more efficient than multiple single-column indexes.

From ["How MySQL Uses Indexes" on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html):

*Suppose that you issue the following SELECT statement:*

*`mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;`*

*If a multiple-column index exists on col1 and col2, the appropriate rows can be fetched directly. If separate single-column indexes exist on col1 and col2, the optimizer will attempt to use the Index Merge optimization (see Section 8.3.1.4, “Index Merge Optimization”), or attempt to find the most restrictive index by deciding which index finds fewer rows and using that index to fetch the rows.**

Thus, you could consider creating an index, as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX id_journey_day_id_day ON journey_day (journey, day);
```

in which case, the index would be used by the following query:

```
SELECT journey.id
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id AND journey_day.day = 3
JOIN service ON journey.service = service.id
JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pl.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = "TMTL";
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I tried a composite index as you suggested and sadly the query still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Did you try running just `SELECT * FROM journey_day where journey_day.journey = <some value> AND journey_day.day = 3;` and viewing the EXPLAIN PLAN? The index should be used in this case.