# Slow where clause on inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

```
SELECT journey.id
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN service ON journey.service = service.id
JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pl.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = "TMTL"
Above is an SQL query that takes on average 0.1 - 0.3 seconds to run.
```

For some reason, as soon as a I append `AND journey_day.day = 3` to the WHERE clause it adds an extra 4 seconds to the execution time. It is for this reason that I am posting this question.

Every column in the journey_day table has indexing of some sort.

```
id(INT 11) | journey(VARCHAR 128) | day(TINYINT 1)
```

The id is the primary key, the journey and day columns are both indexed. The table is joined with absolutely no problems, but as soon as the WHERE clause questions the table, execution time goes up by far too much for my liking.

The `journey_day` table is just there to determine which day the journey runs on. For example, if a journey runs on Wednesday and Thursdays, the journey would have its identifier in the journey column and then 3, same thing in another row but with 4.

Any ideas why this huge delay in execution time is happening?

Result of an EXPLAIN prepended to the query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFXVo.png

Comment: unspecified JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN in MySQL.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333497/where-clause-on-join-adding-4-seconds-to-execution-time#comment39495567_25333497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how many of the fields which are JOINed or conditioned, are indexed. Most possibly, journey_day.day is not indexed, which makes filtering on it quite slow.

One of the ways to check your query is to run `[EXPLAIN][1]` on it (in MySQL console):

```
EXPLAIN <yourquery>
```

It will give you detailed plan of how your query is run, how many rows are going to be checked and whether it uses indexes from the related tables.

What you can also do (which *might* help but not guaranteed) is wrap your whole query into that one filter, so that you apply it to the result of the first query.

```
SELECT journey.id FROM (
SELECT journey.id id, journey_day.day jday
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN service ON journey.service = service.id
JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pl.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = "TMTL") qq
WHERE qq.jday=3;
```

Comment: Your query is about 10 times longer (wrapped query) to execute. Also, I have listed the indexes in the question, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN query. Neither of which have helped :(

Comment: Can you post the results of EXPLAIN here?

Comment: Well, your EXPLAIN tells that for most of the tables in the JOIN, no indexes are used. That means if you want to run your query faster, you have to add indexes to the fields on which you JOIN or filter. For example, try to add index to `journey_day.day` column and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes but like I said, there already is an index on that column

Comment: EXPLAIN does not use these indexes, in any case.

Comment: Well, you actually query on _two_ fields in `journey_day`. You'd need a composite index in that case (e.g (day, journey)), which does not exist. And many indexes there are based on strings, so they are quite long, and might not be very helpful.

Comment: @Ashalynd I just added another UNIQUE index across both the `day` and `journey` columns and it's still the same speed :< - I'm sure the lower string lengths would affect the speed but I don't think it would explain all of this

Comment: Did you add composite index? I.e. for _both_ columns at the same time? On the other hand, there are also other tables with a lot of conditions in that query. You have to keep tinkering with indexing and check what EXPLAIN tells you, may be you'll succeed. No easy recipe here.